# Xamarin.Forms Scroll screen which contains a ListView

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm new to Xamarin.Forms and I started to implement a product screen which contains a Title, a SearchBar, some filtering controls and the main ListView.

Everything works fine, the ListView displays the items and they scroll as you would expect.

My goal is to have the entire screen scroll, not just the ListView item, and the reason is because the top elements occupy a pretty large amount of space.

How would this be possbile to implement in XAML? I tried adding a ScrollView to contain everything but of course there are issues adding a ListView inside a ScrollView.

Thank You.

Comment: it is generally a bad idea to have one scrollable control nested inside of another one.  This makes navigation of the page very difficult for the user.  A better approach would be to make your top elements smaller, or hideable, or possibly put them in the header of the list view

Comment: Thank you. I think adding the controls inside the header is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Placing ListView inside a ScrollView is not a good idea but still, we are trying to achieve it by writing the Custom Renderer because such features are available in native platforms.

Create **NestedListView** class :

```
public class NestedListView: Xamarin.Forms.ListView  
{  
   
}
```

Create **NestedListViewDroid** in Androi project:

```
public class NestedListViewDroid: ListViewRenderer  
{  
    public NestedListViewDroid(Android.Content.Context context) : base(context)  
    {  

    }  
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.ListView> e)  
    {  
        base.OnElementChanged(e);  
        if(e.NewElement != null)  
        {  
            var listview = this.Control as Android.Widget.ListView;  
            listview.NestedScrollingEnabled = true;  
        }  
    }  
}
```

then use like:

```
<ScrollView Padding="20">  
    <StackLayout>  
        ...

        <controls:NestedListView  x:Name="listview">  
        </controls:NestedListView >  

    ... 
    </StackLayout>  
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `TranslationY` of the listview then it is scroll, so it move the ListView.Header part up.
Michael Ridland have a very good blog post about it, have a look:
[facebook listview scroll with translationY](https://michaelridland.com/mobile/beautiful-xamarin-facebook-clone-in-xamarin-forms/)

Answer (score 0):

Bindable layout could be useful

```
   <ScrollView>
            <StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="">
                <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                    <!-- Your ListView DataTemplate -->
                </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
            </StackLayout>
   </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use StackLayout.

```
 <ScrollView>
            <StackLayout>
                <ListView>
                </ListView>
            </StackLayout>
 </ScrollView>
```